# MPI Gather Sparse Vector

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, sparse-matrix

Hi I have the result bool C array (size of sizeResults) and it is very sparse as most of the values are false.
I am using MPI_GATHER to gather this array from all workers however it is very time consuming...

```
MPI_Gather(result, sizeResults, MPI_BYTE, result_final, sizeResults, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

is there a more efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several, depending on just how sparse your array is. One trivial method is to condense your array of bools into a bit array, reducing it to 1/8 of its original size.

Other things you could do:

1. Instead of `Gather`ing the bool values themselves, `Gatherv` the indices of the `true` values. For instance, if a process has the array `{ T, F, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, T }`, then it would send the array `{ 0, 6, 9 }`.
2. If you want to get creative, think of your array as consisting of segments, where a segment is defined as a `true` value followed by all the `false` values leading up to the next `true` value. Using the above example, your 3 segments would be `{ T, F, F, F, F, F }`, `{ T, F, F }`, and `{ T }`. Now all you need to `Gatherv` from each process is the length of each segment. In fairness, this generally isn't any more efficient than method 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can i use a bit array in MPI? I finally did use a buffer to send them and receive them by the worker the same way as gatherv do you think that reallocating a vector and sending it with gatherv would take less time?

Comment: As a matter of fact, method 1 and 2 have exactly the same efficiency (give or take the pre- and post-processing time) and there exists a linear transformation that links both vectors (a lower triangular matrix with `1`s under the main diagonal and `0`s on and over it and its inverse).

Comment: @iassael: MPI doesn't have specific support for bit arrays, but you can simply send one as an array of `MPI_BYTE` and it will arrive exactly as it was. I can't tell you if this would be better or worse than any other method for your specific scenario: you should measure it yourself.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I just came back from a 12+ hour workday, so this may just be fatigue speaking, but I think there are certain edge cases where method 2 can be more efficient. Assuming that one has a guarantee that `true` values occur with some minimum frequency, is it not possible that segment lengths can be stored in a smaller data type than array indices (i.e. `short` instead of `int`), and thus lead to a smaller payload?

Comment: It would make perfect sense. I was speaking about the general case. And mind that using `MPI_Gatherv` would require an additional gather operation before that with the reduced vector lengths. With high-latency comm systems it might make more sense to simply gather the whole bit vectors.